# add hours to new Date only showing NaN

Tags: javascript, date

I know there are many questions like this when I googled it, and I cannot seem to make it work. I use Safari as my bowser, which is new to me since OS X Yosemite.  But, I cannot figure this one out.

All I am trying to do, using Keith Wood countdown plugin, is get a datetime from a database and add 2 hours.  Here is the code:

```
$(data).each(function(key, value) {

    var box = '';

    box += '<div class="outterBox" id="qBox'+value.qid+'" name="'+value.qid+'">'+value.question+'</div>';
    box += '<div id="timer'+value.qid+'"></div>';


    var newYear = new Date(value.added);
    var endtime = newYear.setHours(newYear.getHours() + (2));

    console.log(value.added);
    console.log(endtime);

    $('#listQuestions').append(box);
    $('#timer'+value.qid).countdown({until: endtime});

});
```

It seems pretty simple, I tried to make the new adjusted date (with the extra two hours) a new Date again, but that gave me the same problem.

Here is the output in console:

> With console.log(new Date(endtime);
>
> 2014-10-24 19:48:01
>
> Invalid Date
>
> 2014-10-24 19:39:14
>
> Invalid Date
>
> 2014-10-24 19:30:23
>
> Invalid Date

and:

> With console.log(endtime):
>
> 2014-10-24 19:56:14
>
> NaN
>
> 22014-10-24 19:48:01
>
> NaN
>
> 2014-10-24 19:39:14
>
> NaN
>
> 2014-10-24 19:30:23
>
> NaN

Worth noting I have tried many examples I have found with adding hours to dates, but none of them worked, so this example seems the most logical, but I am doing something stupidly wrong. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

With the help from below, I have some issues which perhaps I did not really make clear in my explaining.

It looks like the date coming in from a cycle jquery(ajax)/php/database/php(echo)/jquery(ajax) looks like this:

> 2014-10-24 19:30:23

I do not think the above is a valid date, but a string. I think this because if I add this:

```
newYear = new Date(value.added);
```

I get **Invalid Date**. So any getHours() request cannot be evaluated, and so gives an error.

I have tried breaking down the string, and recreate a new date like this:

```
var dt  = newYear.split(/\-|\s/);
endDate = new Date(dt[2] + '/' + dt[1] + '/' + dt[0] + ' ' + dt[3]);
console.log(endDate.getFullYear());
```

But the above gives me a **NaN**.

The reason I think its a string is if i put the following code:

```
if(String(value.added)){
                console.log('isString Date')
            } else {
                console.log('is Not String Date')
            }
```

console prints **isString Date**

And this explains why the countdown works, but does not give an accurate time.  The database is mySQL.

So is it because the time is being passed through php, and then JS, as the database is column is set to datetime ?

Comment: What does `console.log(newYear);` give you?

Comment: It looks like `value.added` is not a valid parameter for Date's constructor. Date's constructor expects a string that is formatted in a specific way(http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.4.2) or a number representing milliseconds since epoch time.

Comment: @MatthewStrawbridge newYear gives me '2014-10-24 19:30:23'

Comment: @Sacho value.added is turned into a new Date, so would that not change whatever the databased stored it as, into the correct construct ?

Comment: Where is `value.added` turned into a Date? From what? What's the effect? Try posting an example of all your code, e.g. on jsfiddle. Alternatively, learn how to use chrome's debugger tools and find out the actual values of things.

Comment: @Sacho I have updated my question which might help some more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case I tested with the last update to the question, and adding the 'T' fixes the problem:

```
var newYear = new Date(value.added.replace(" ", "T"));
```

That should fix the problem. Since there should be at most one space, there should be no need for any additional tests.

---

Update as my first answer was assuming the start date was invalid. End date is actually the problem:

```
var endtime = newYear.setHours(newYear.getHours() + (2));
```

That is certainly taking a risk as it may not work in all implementations. Plus it modifies newYear directly, so I would not otherwise see the point in creating a new variable.

I would suggest the following to fix the problem:

```
var endtime = new Date(newYear.getTime() + 7200000);
```

where 7,200,000 is 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000, or the number of milliseconds in 2 hours.

---

According to ECMAScript 5, the date format is parsed using the `parse()` function (15.9.4.2).

This tells you that the language tries to convert your string with a format similar to what `x.toUTCString()` would produce, which should be what you show in your output. This should match the simplified ISO 8601 format, without the need for the 'T' between the date and time:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.sssZ
```

From what I understand, the `.sssZ` is not required, but you could try something like this:

```
var newYear = new Date(value.added + ".000Z");
```

You may want to also check `15.9.5.42 toUTCString()` and `15.9.5.43 toISOString()`.

However, if you are saying that you previously extracted a string from a `Date` object using `toUTCString()` and the conversion going back fails, then there is a bug in that JavaScript implementation, because ECMAScript clearly says that such a round trip should return the exact same value:

> If x is any Date object whose milliseconds amount is zero within a particular implementation of ECMAScript, then all of the following expressions should produce the same numeric value in that implementation, if all the properties referenced have their initial values:

```
  x.valueOf()
  Date.parse(x.toString())
  Date.parse(x.toUTCString())
  Date.parse(x.toISOString())
```

Comment: `value.added + '.000Z'` **outputs** 2014-10-24 20:14:30.000Z; `new Date(value.added + '.000Z')` **outputs** Invalid Date; `newYear.setHours(newYear.getHours()) + 2` **outputs** NaN.  Makes little sense to me :(

Comment: Might be worth noting also, that just using `value.added` does give me the correct date/time, and works with the countdown plugin.

Comment: Ah. Thank you for pointing out that the problem was in the end date. I see that clearly in your question now. I updated my answer with a fix for that specific point, although maybe you need a Unix time in which case you do not have to do `new Date(...)`, obviously.

Comment: I have updated my question which might help some more.

Comment: Okay, I added an update. The fix seems to just be to add the 'T' between the date and time. PHP/AJAX cannot return anything else than strings really. A string such as `"33"` will automatically be transformed to a number (except with the + operator, in which case you may get a concatenation). There is one way to get numbers as such: use JSON to convert the data received in strings and numbers as defined in the source document, and also objects and arrays (but still no dates).